# Show div at a certain video time and hide it at another

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I'm trying to show a div at a certain video time and make it disappear 2 seconds later so I'm trying this but it's not working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#element_1").hide(); 
 document.getElementById('bgvid').addEventListener("timeupdate", 
 function() {
 if(this.currentTime > 5) {
$("#element_1").show();
    }
    else if(this.currentTime > 7) {
        $("#element_1").hide();
    } 
});
});
```

It shows the div only at 5 seconds after the video starts but it doesn't hides it at 7.

Comment: why don't you use `delay`? like: `if(this.currentTime > 5){$("#element_1").show().delay(2000).fadeOut()}`?

Comment: In fact it disappears this way, but sincethe time is then also greater than 5 from that point on, it appears again.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working has I need it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#element_1").hide(); 
document.getElementById('bgvid').addEventListener("timeupdate", 
function() {
    if(this.currentTime > 5 && this.currentTime < 10) {
$("#element_1").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#element_1").hide();
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of going to JQ you can achieve it with plain JS itself

https://codepen.io/subbu1191/pen/QvjKNQ

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.ontimeupdate = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = vid.currentTime;
     if((vid.currentTime >= 5) && (vid.currentTime <= 7)){
      document.getElementById('headerContent').style.display = 'block';
     }else{
      document.getElementById('headerContent').style.display = 'none';
     }
 }
```